# No callback function for opera with animate.enhanced plugin

Tags: jquery, animation, opera

So, here's my simple function that is called in $(document).ready

```
function animateDiv(object){
   var newq=makeNewPosition();
   var oldq=object.offset();
   var speed=calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);
   object.animate({top:newq[0],left:newq[1], opacity:randomOpacity()},speed, function(){
     console.log("LOL");
     animateDiv(object);
   });
};
```

My problem is, the callback of the animate function never fires in Opera, tho it works in every other browser. If I don't use the animate.enhanced plugin it works properly, but the plugin makes my animations much smoother so I don't want to just drop it.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: I'm not sure how this plugin works. Can you put a demo on jsfiddle or link to the plugin's demos or something?